# Prove that the correspondance is an isomorphism from $O_2$ to a subgroup of $SO_3$

Tags: group-theory

Prove that the correspondance
$$ A\rightarrow\begin{cases}
\begin{bmatrix}
A & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\text{if $A \in SO_2$}\\
\begin{bmatrix}
A & 0\\
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
\text{if $A \in O_2 - SO_2$}\\
\end{cases} $$
 is an isomphism from $O_2$ to a subgroup of $SO_3$

I have no idea where to go from here to prove this.

Comment: Have you shown that it is a well-defined function? After that, you need to prove that is a homomorphism and that it is injective. Where are you stuck?

Comment: I am stuck at the beginning since i don't know where to start (except for the fact that i have to prove that A is a bijection and a homomorphism).  I do not really get these groups and was hoping to get more insight with this example.

Comment: Are the groups $O_2$ and $SO_2$ over reals or over a finite field? If over reals, then the tag [tag:finite-groups] feels misplaced.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\phi\colon G\to H,\ \phi'\colon G\to H'$ be two group homomorphisms.

Then $\psi\colon G\to H\times H'$ defined as $\psi(g) = \big(\phi(g),\phi'(g)\big)$ is also a group homomorphism. (routine verification)

Now take $G=H=O(2)$,  $\phi$ as identity,  $H'=\{\pm1\}$ and $\phi'$ as the determinant homomorphism. And note that $H\times H'$ is a subgroup of $O(3)$.  You should be able complete the details now.